# Removing const qualifier from type-inference return type

Tags: c++, decltype, const-cast

Quick question for the folks out there. I have the function signature below that under some but not all circumstances returns a const type qualifier on the return type.

```
template <typename U,
          typename V,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<V>::value, int>/* = 0*/ > // SFINAE dummy
Vector3D<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())> operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix)
```

How can I use `const_cast` to remove any const qualifiers returned by `decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())`?

Comment: You mean like [`std::remove_const_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)?

Comment: @Useless That looks like an answer :) I can't find a good dupe target either.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Useless worked like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is [`std::remove_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
template <typename U,
          typename V,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<V>::value, int>/* = 0*/ > // SFINAE dummy
Vector3D<std::remove_const_t<decltype(std::declval<U>() / std::declval<V>())>>
operator/ (const Vector3D<U>& p_vector, const Matrix3D<V>& p_matrix)
```

If `U/V` might return a reference you might want [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) instead.

Comment: It might trip up a beginner if you say you're going to use `std::remove_const` and then in your example you use `std::remove_const_t`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @bolov worked like a charm :). Still learning one baby step at a time =)

Comment: [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is also a frequent tool (remove reference first too (and volatile) for regular case and handle array, and function).